How to acheive overlapping design in flutter
Im trying to implement the ui as below. i have tried with stack with two containers , with one positioned.

but the result is like this

what is the correct way to achieve this ?

Add the padding between red base and screen base to y component of both stacked widgets.

can you share the code?

use Stack , or use Transform and translate for y axis

https://pub.dev/packages/assorted_layout_widgets

This is how I would do it:
SizedBox(
  width: 300,
  height: 400,
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 18),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.orange[300],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        ),
      ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            backgroundColor: Colors.red[500],
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32),
          ),
          child: const Text(
            "Back",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);

Result:


You can wrap your stack in a sizedbox of height more than your large container.
SizedBox(
    height: 200,
    child: Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 160,
          width: 250,
          color: Colors.yellow,
        ),
        Positioned(
          bottom: -2,
          child: Container(
            width: 80,
            height: 40,
            color: Colors.red,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: const Text("Back"),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  )

You can refer to the above code to get the desired approach. Hope it helps.

There is property in stack called clipBehavior by default it is set as Clip.hardEdge meaning it will clip any overflowing part from the widget.
you can set it as Clip.none and also mind the parent size of Stack. So that it does not overflow over other widgets
